# KHTTP android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException on POST request

Tags: http, kotlin

When I try to do a POST request using khttp, I get this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.emir.getirme, PID: 9379
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1448)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:355)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:616)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:145)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:141)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:163)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHeaderFields(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:223)
        at khttp.responses.GenericResponse$Companion.getCookieJar$khttp(GenericResponse.kt:35)
        at khttp.responses.GenericResponse$Companion$defaultEndInitializers$3.invoke(GenericResponse.kt:116)
        at khttp.responses.GenericResponse$Companion$defaultEndInitializers$3.invoke(GenericResponse.kt:32)
        at khttp.responses.GenericResponse$connection$2.invoke(GenericResponse.kt:164)
        at khttp.responses.GenericResponse$connection$2.invoke(GenericResponse.kt:30)
        at khttp.responses.GenericResponse.openRedirectingConnection$khttp(GenericResponse.kt:124)
        at khttp.responses.GenericResponse.getConnection(GenericResponse.kt:163)
        at khttp.responses.GenericResponse.getRaw(GenericResponse.kt:207)
        at khttp.responses.GenericResponse.getContent(GenericResponse.kt:216)
        at khttp.responses.GenericResponse.init$khttp(GenericResponse.kt:350)
        at khttp.KHttp.request(KHttp.kt:59)
        at khttp.KHttp.post(KHttp.kt:48)
        at khttp.KHttp.post$default(KHttp.kt:47)
        at com.emir.getirme.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda-1(MainActivity.kt:51)
        at com.emir.getirme.MainActivity.lambda$3IBZyc9kPzUSvfk0gsgNPVZ2ETU(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.emir.getirme.-$$Lambda$MainActivity$3IBZyc9kPzUSvfk0gsgNPVZ2ETU.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

This is my code:

```
khttp.post(
    "http://127.0.0.1:5000/order",
    headers = mapOf(
        "address" to address.toString(),
        "items" to Json.encodeToString(listOf("Su x1", "Gofret x5", "Dondurma x1")),
        "price" to "100",
        "orderer" to name.toString(),
        "phone" to phone.toString()
    ),
)
```

I'm trying to send a request to a [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/) server running in my local PC. The server is not the problem as I tested it with Python.

The code is not inside an async task or any type of async function. I tried to use [`khttp.async`](https://khttp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced.html#asynchronous-requests) but I didn't have `khttp.async` for some reason.

Comment: how do you call khttp.post, from Activity, viewModel?

Comment: @mightyWOZ It's inside a `setOnClickListener{}` which is inside my `AppCompatActivity` https://imgur.com/QGOq28V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the exception message is very clear, If you want to understand in detail why this happens, please [read](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html)

As to how you can fix this, you can use [kotln coroutines](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines) for this, once you have included the given dependencies in your build, you can do the following

```
// Start network request on a background thread using coroutine
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { 
    khttp.post(
        "http://127.0.0.1:5000/order",
         headers = mapOf(
            "address" to address.toString(),
            "items" to Json.encodeToString(listOf("Su x1", "Gofret x5", "Dondurma x1")),
            "price" to "100",
            "orderer" to name.toString(),
            "phone" to phone.toString()
        ),
    )
}
```